# How to get previously added joins back from Knex QueryBuilder?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I have code that builds a Knex query in a multi-step process. I want to make some utility methods that do things like append the schema to the already-existing joins.

I believe I can add the schema to the main `from` clause using `query.withSchema('myDatabase.dbo')`. But I don't currently see a way to get the joins back so I can loop through them and add the schema to those.

In general, I don't see a way to get any values back that have already been added to the query builder. Is there a way to to this?

For example:

```js
const query = knex.from('myTable1 as t1')
  .select(['myCol1'])
  .join('myTable2 as t2', 't1.myCol1', 't2.myCol2')
  .join('myTable3 as t3', 't1.myCol1', 't3.myCol3')
  .where('t1.myCol4', 'myValue');


function addSchema(query, schema) {
  query.withSchema(schema);

  const joins = // how to get the joins from the query?
  for (const join of joins) {
    join.withSchema(schema);
  }
}

addSchema(query, 'mySchema1');
```

The above example is a simplified version of the specific problem I'm trying to solve. In actuality, I need to take one query and make it a union query for multiple databases with the same database structure. So I want to write the query once and then loop through the databases, clone the query for each, and add it as a union to the original query. But I need the database/schema name added to the `FROM` table and all of the joins on each of the cloned queries. I have everything else worked out if I can just figure out how to add the schema to the joins after they've been added to the query builder.

Answer (score 1):

#### Example of `knex.raw()` and Knex QueryBuilder with placeholders

I prefixed every table names with a placeholder for schema, like '#'.

JavaScript code:

```js
const knex = require("knex")({ client: "mysql" });

const readOnlyQuery = knex
  .select("*")
  .from("#.users as u")
  .leftJoin("#.pets as p", "u.id", "p.idUser")
  .where("u.id", 1);

// Prevent modification of this object
Object.freeze(readOnlyQuery);

/**
 * Returns a new Knex QueryBuilder object with a query that contains the given schema.
 * @param {Builder} queryBuilder
 * @param {String} schema
 */
function buildQueryWithSchema(queryBuilder, schema) {
  return knex.raw(
    queryBuilder.toString().replaceAll("`#`", "`" + schema + "`")
  );
}

const queryBuilderSchemaPublic = buildQueryWithSchema(readOnlyQuery, "public");
console.log(queryBuilderSchemaPublic.toString());

const queryBuilderSchemaPrivate = buildQueryWithSchema(readOnlyQuery,"private");
console.log(queryBuilderSchemaPrivate.toString());
```

Output:

```sql
select * from `public`.`users` as `u` left join `public`.`pets` as `p` on `u`.`id` = `p`.`idUser` where `u`.`id` = 1
select * from `private`.`users` as `u` left join `private`.`pets` as `p` on `u`.`id` = `p`.`idUser` where `u`.`id` = 1
```

#### Testing on NPM Playground

[Link to live example on NPM Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/npm-playground-forked-sv3ptz?file=/src/index.js) (External link)

#### References

- [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. I already have a query built and stored in the `query` constant with joins already added without schemas, and I want to add schemas later, after the query has already been built. The idea is to take one query, clone it multiple times and create a big union query with different schemas in each union.

Comment: I added an example of custom methods.

Comment: You're still defining the query in the method. The point of the question is to pass the query (with the joins already added) into the method and have it append the schema to the already-built query. The method needs to be reusable for many different queries, so the tables and joins cannot be hard-coded there. I want to build a bunch of queries without schemas and then later pass the fully built query into this method and have it add the schema to all of the referenced tables.

Comment: OP, do you have any inconveniences with this new example?

Comment: I think it's the closest I'm going to get. I don't think we can really do exactly what I want. I will award the bounty. Thanks for your effort!